# Detect breakage in wires

Tags: sensor

I need a device for some experiments that could help me detect when a wire breaks or disconnects. I need to be able to tell exactly how long it took for the circuit to break too. The only purpose of the circuit is to test how long it takes to break, the voltage would be run very low. Would a raspberry pi be able to do this? Would it be able to do this for multiple samples at the same time? I have almost no experience with working with electronics.

EDIT: To answer the questions from KDM:

1. The wire length is approximately 6 ft, 20 or 22 gauge. the breakage test is on a section of conductive paint approximately 6 inches long and 2-4 mm wide.
2. I was planning on using 3V of power
3. It doesn't have to be extremely precise, anything around a tenth of a second of error or less would be more than accurate enough.

Comment: the answers to both of your questions is `very likely yes` ... it depends on the desired accuracy of `when a wire breaks`

Comment: research `connecting a switch to Raspberry Pi` ... you are actually asking `how to detect when a switch opens`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't actually make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: Yes.
Q2: Yes.

I imagine you'd use a digital input to detect the presence of a voltage. On the Raspberry Pi, if the voltage drops below 1.8V, this would render logic 0 into your program. (I.e. wire is broken.) A voltage between 1.8V and 3.3V will render logic 1 (wire is unbroken).

NB: An input voltage above 3.3V will break your Raspberry Pi.

You could potentially measure 26 of these in parallel.

Note, the above is a "no electronics required" solution. The voltage you put on the wire to detect if it's broken will be a feature of the length (and material) of the wire: the voltage will naturally drop along its length.

Further: "Exactly" when it breaks is not particularly scientific. An Arduino would be more deterministic (maybe to the nearest microsecond) than a micro running an Operating System (maybe the nearest millisecond). An Arduino would also be less expensive to replace.

If you were to modify the question to state:

1. appx length of wire (including material and cross-section)
2. appx excitation voltage
3. how accurately is "exactly when it breaks"

You could get a better answer.